# How to solve Bad Configuration Option: UseDNS?

Tags: server, ssh, login

The delay for ssh login is too long.

```
$ ssh 192.168.1.7
casper@192.168.1.7's password:
(waiting... Too Long... 26 seconds...)
(waiting... Too Long... 26 seconds...)
(waiting... Too Long... 26 seconds...)
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-62-generic x86_64)
...
...
```

I found [a solution](https://superuser.com/a/359345/324950) that configure the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` as if the following.

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no         # yes -> no
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes   # no  -> yes
UseDNS no                       # added
```

But when I try to do ssh login, I got the following error message.

```
$ ssh 192.168.1.7
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 57: Bad configuration option: usedns
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Why? How can I speed up the SSH login?

Comment: I answered about the error message (useDNS belongs in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`). If you want to speed up your ssh, we need to see the output of `ssh -vv` (or `-vvv`) to see which part it is getting stuck on.

Comment: When I execute `ssh -vv` or `ssh -vvv`, it only shows me the usage guide: `usage: ssh [-...]`.

Comment: No, I meant `ssh -vvv 192.168.1.7`, you need to actually try to connect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a *server* option, not a client one. It should be set in the machine you are connecting *to* (the server) and not on the machine you are connecting *from* (the client). Also, it needs to be in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and not `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. The former is the configuration file used when the machine is acting as a server (receiving connections) and the latter when the machine is a client (connecting to another machine).

Mind you, I very much doubt this will make any difference in the connection times you're seeing, but you may as well try it.

Comment: I already tried it for the server side, but it does not work. What is the problem making the long delay?

Comment: @Casper this should solve the `Bad configuration option`, not speed things up.